# Ajax async calls blocking other script

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
                    var jsonData=false;
                    var maxRecords=0;
                    var successRecords=0;
                    var failedRecords=0;
```

After upload is finished the script passes the file name($filename) to parsing script. The parsing script returns json object containing all ITEMS in file.

```
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'ajax/process-file.php',
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType:"json",
                        async:false,
                        data:{filename:'<?php echo $newFile ?>'}
                    }).success(function(data){
                        jsonData=data;
                        maxRecords=jsonData.length;
                        $("#record-found").html(maxRecords);
                    });
```

I'm running another script for individual ITEM.

```
                       for(i=0;i<maxRecords;i++){
                            //AJAX CALL FOR INDIVIDUAL RECORD
                            $.ajax({
                                url:'ajax/save-single-planitem.php',
                                type: "POST",
                                async:false,
                                data:{item:jsonData[i]}
                            }).success(function(data){
                                console.log(data);
                                //IF RECORD WAS SUCCESFULLY ADDED OR UPDATED
                                if(data['result']=="SUCCESS"){
                                    $("#records-success").html(successRecords++);
                                }
                                //IF RECORD WAS NOT ADDED
                                if(data['result']=="FAILED"){
                                    $("#records-failed").html(failedRecords++);
                                }
                            });
                        }
```

Now the problem is with this small part

```
                        maxRecords=jsonData.length;
                        $("#record-found").html(maxRecords);
```

in first ajax call.

This makes the changes after all the execution is done. Not to mention that other attempts to change HTML are also reflected after all the calls are complete.

I've already tried placing the code after the ajax call where async request is complete. 
Completely stumped on how to approach.

jQuery/javscript solution will be appreciated.(Without any additional library load)

Comment: Are you really running synchronous (blocking) Ajax calls?  Why?

Comment: First one I have to. To fetch records for further processing. Second one to get correct values for success and failures. Because then I've to let users choose what to do with failed attempts.

Comment: @Rohan210 There is no need in synchronous request in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should really try to make requests async. Otherwise you'll have to introduce some sort `setTimeout(makeAnotherRequest, 0)` hack into your code.

This is how it can be done "ajax way".

```
function getAll(fileName) { 
    return $.get('ajax/process-file.php', {filename: fileName});    
}

function getItem(item) {
    return $.post('ajax/save-single-planitem.php', item);
}

var succeeded = 0, failed = 0;

getAll('<?php echo $newFile ?>')
.done(function(items) {
       $("#record-found").html(items.length); 
})
.done(function(items) {
  items.forEach(function(item) {
      getItem(item).done(function(result) {
          if(result.result === 'SUCCESS') $("#records-success").html(succeeded++);
          if(result.result === 'FAILED') $("#records-failed").html(failed);
      });
  });  
});
```

Comment: I've tried adding setTimeout(function(){},6000); after the first ajax call before updating HTML. Didn't work. Will try this and get back again.

Comment: @Rohan210 BTW blocking requests on UI thread are actually deprecated.

Comment: I've tried using the method suggested by you. forEach(??) gives error. Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function .. Also is there a reason why you used multiple done() on getAll('<?php echo $newFile ?>')

Comment: My problem comes from the service which is called by my server side script in second PHP file(save-single-item.php). The service does not allow for multiple request from a same server at the same time. So the second request must be made async

Comment: `forEach` is an array method. Multiple `done` is simple logic separation "one function does one thing".

Comment: items.length was giving wrong number so I made a few modifications. And I'm still unable to achieve what I set out to do in the first place.

Comment: I changed it to data=$.parseJSON(items); This gives the actual number in both don()